# Replace dash in dataframe using str_replace_all

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am flummoxed by this basic problem. I have a dataframe that has dashes instead of zero values e.g.

```
example <- data.frame(Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "March"),
                  Units = c("100", "-", "300"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Now I thought str_replace_all would work:

```
replace <- example %>%
  str_replace_all("-", "0")
```

But I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

I need to get do conversion first before converting "Units" into numeric e.g.

```
replace <- example %>%
  str_replace_all("-", "0") %>%
  mutate_at(2, as.numeric)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% mutate_at(vars(Units), list(~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.,'-','0'))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks `mutate_at` works for me as my real data I have 21 columns with dashes e.g.

```
replace <- real_data %>%
    mutate_at(vars(2:22),list(~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.,'-','0')))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `stringr::str_replace_all` works on a vector, not on a whole dataframe:

```
example$Units = example$Units %>%
    str_replace_all("-", "0") %>%
    as.numeric
```

or

```
example <- example %>%
  mutate(Units = Units %>% 
           str_replace_all("-", "0") %>%
           as.numeric)
```

or you might more concisely use:

```
example$Units = readr::parse_number(example$Units)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 0):

df <- replace(df, df == “-“, 0)